# How to use canvas as CSS background in chrome 48 in directly way?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Chrome 48 has removed the javascript API: document.getCSSCanvasContext("2d", id,width,height) and CSS API: --webkit-canvas(id). I was able to run webkit inspector on chrome previous versions but not on version 48.

Some code used to use these APIs to specify an element background image using canvas in CSS and draw the canvas in javascript like the following:

```js
const context = document.getCSSCanvasContext("2d",background-canvas , 50, 50);
context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

```css
.container {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background-image: -webkit-canvas(background-canvas);
  }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 </div>
```

A replacement API in chrome 48 is to create a canvas elements inside the target element and use CSS to simulate background like the following:

```js
var can1 = document.getElementById('background1');
can1.width=50;
can1.height=50
const ctx1 = can1.getContext('2d');
ctx1.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);


var can2 = document.getElementById('background2');
can2.width=50;
can2.height=50
const ctx2 = can2.getContext('2d');
ctx2.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 255, 0)";
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

```css
.container {
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
 }
.container .background1,.background2 {
  display:none;
}
.container:active .background1 {
  display:block;
}
.container:not(:active) .background2 {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id='target' class='container'>
  <canvas id='background1' class='background1'></canvas>
  <canvas id='background2' class='background2'></canvas>
</div>
```

Please try to click on the above DIV, the background will change.

But this solution is not a directly solution and it needs to insert multiple canvases into an element. Also it need to write more complex CSS than --webkit-canvas.

If there is not a direct API to do this, what is a simple solution to use canvas as an element's background on chrome 48 and later versions?

Comment: I didn't know about this API, but I don't see the advantage of this CSS canvas over a true HTMLCanvasElement if you need js anyway. eventListeners are easily added, resizing is not so hard either. Could you tell us what were the real advantages you had with this only-supported-by-a-few-versions-of-a-single-browser API ? I'm pretty sure one would be able to reproduce it with just a few lines of highly supported js.

Comment: I need to:

1) generated images(A and B) as an element's background image.
2) Select background from A and B using CSS selectors.

CSS is good at solving complex cases using its selectors, by different classes and different nesting relations. It can define complex rules to determine which image should be used as background. 

Solutions I can think are:
1) using HTMLCanvasElement and JS event handlers and dataUrl to set background. Disadvantage: It can't use CSS selectors, and has to write many JS conditions.
or
2) inserting multiple HTMLCanvasElements and using CSS. Disadvantage: js initialize